# Division of dates to create percentage SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, percentage, division

I am trying to do write in a function to subtract a few dates, then divide them together, add 1 then * 100 to get an overall % complete.

```
((SYSDATETIME() - proj.proj_scheduledDate)/(proj.proj_dueDate - proj.proj_scheduledDate + 1)) * 100 as 'percent done
```

returns

> Operand data type datetime is invalid for divide operator.

What do I need to do to get this query to work? THANKS!

Comment: When you divide dates what do you expect to get?

Comment: @yosi he expects to receive a `%` complete. So If the start date was `1/1/2013` and the end date is `6/6/2013`. `3/3/2013` would be something like `50%`.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest using [**DATEDIFF()**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) with `dd` for a day `datepart` -- you can easily get the percentage of days completed - or go to smaller `datepart` values if you need to.

> Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart
>   boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.

Comment: can you give me an example how i might write this out?

Comment: the dates stretch across multiple years sometimes, this is the querey that i got to work but its not returning the correct values

((DATEDIFF(DAYOFYEAR, GETDATE(), proj.proj_scheduledDate)) / (DATEDIFF(DAYOFYEAR, proj.proj_duedate, proj.proj_scheduledDate))) as 'test'

Comment: What is incorrect with your results? You might want to try a smaller `dartpart` which is suggested above. There's a list in the link.

Comment: I got it to work. but now im having an issue of casting it to a decimal so i can convert to %

(DATEDIFF(DAYOFYEAR, proj.proj_scheduledDate, GETDATE())) / 
(DATEDIFF(DAYOFYEAR, proj.proj_scheduledDate, proj.proj_duedate)+1) as 'test'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    FLOOR((DATEDIFF(NOW(), proj.proj_scheduledDate) / DATEDIFF(proj.proj_dueDate, proj.proj_scheduledDate)) * 100)
FROM
    foo;
```

Comment: Tried this but its telling me datediff requires 3 arguments

Comment: That's true, [`DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate)`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp).

Comment: cast((DATEDIFF(DAYOFYEAR, proj.proj_scheduledDate, GETDATE())) as decimal) /  
(DATEDIFF(DAYOFYEAR, proj.proj_scheduledDate, proj.proj_duedate)+1)*100 as 'percent complete',